# Swap div and contents on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Been trying to swap 2 divs. When the button is clicked #profeditclick1, #profswitch1 should swap with #hideedit1. At the moment when the button is clicked all the divs just disappear. Thank for your help or guidance.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cart_verwrap" >

    <div class="cart_verbill" *id="profswitch1">

    <div class="btn blue cartprof-btn l-btn txt_fff s16" id="profeditclick1">Edit</div>
    </div>


    <!-- hidden edit profile in css it set to display:none-->
                   <div class="cart_verbill" id="hideedit1">


        </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
 $("#profeditclick1").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var content = $(this).html();
        $('#profswitch1').replaceWith('<div id="hideedit1">' + content + '</div>');
      });
```

UPDATE

Next attempt although doesnt seem to work. i have taken of the display:none and tried to hide it:

```
$("#hideedit1").hide();
$("#profeditclick1").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = $(this).html();
    $('#profswitch1').replaceWith('<div id="hideedit1">' + content + '</div>');
    $("#hideedit1").show();
});
```

Comment: Please only show the relevant code and a minimal representation of it. We don't need to see multiple tables and tons of rows to visualize this problem. Excessive code makes it harder to narrow down where we need to look. Have a read through [mcve]

Comment: Did you wrap your JS code in the document.ready block?

Comment: yes it is in doc ready. On click it appears to swap but leaves it empty so something is working.

Comment: Cleaned it up sorry for the mess

Comment: In the original post, you had two elements with `id="profeditclick1"`. That would need fixing before anything else.

Comment: Instead of moving content around, could you not toggle the two divs in antiphase?

Comment: @ roamer thank you. that was the button id for another dic that needs swapping.

Comment: Not sue what antiphase is.

Comment: Is the issue setting "hideedit1" in the css to "display:none"?

Comment: IS there a way to use script to hide the div "hhideedit1" i think this will solve the problem

Comment: "toggle the two divs in antiphase" simply means show A and hide B. Then, at the next click, show B and hide A.

Comment: Will have a go,  very new to script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may help you. I have added some modification in your HTML.
Please check it and change it as you need.

```js
    jQuery('#hideedit1').hide();
    jQuery('#profeditclick1').click(function(){
      jQuery(this).hide();
      jQuery('#hideedit1').show();
    });
    
      
    jQuery('#hideedit1 #save_edit').click(function(){
      jQuery('#hideedit1').hide();
      jQuery('#profeditclick1').show();
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <div class="cart_verwrap" >
        <div class="cart_verbill">
            <div class="btn blue cartprof-btn l-btn txt_fff s16" id="profeditclick1">Edit</div>
        </div>
        <!-- hidden edit profile in css it set to display:none-->
         <div class="cart_verbill" id="hideedit1">   EDIT PROFILE CONTENT  <button id="save_edit">Save</button>  </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ok. Lets Have a Try @Dee

Comment: It works,butwhere is says (this) hide it is not hiding that div, it just hides the button.

Comment: change it to id of what you want to hide.

Comment: That works, just having issues with it forcing the div next to it, to go under it

Comment: Please post your full code. Then only we know the problem.

Comment: All sorted, had try first first. success. thank you for your help sir.

Comment: Ok.You are Welcome.